how to read json data in groovy
Team,
I am making a call to gerrit server and return is I believe json. From this I am trying to read fields but getting error in the first step itself. any hint? My call to gerrit and storing its response is successful but further reading it is my challenge.
output is
Raw Response: )]}'
{"cherrypick":{"method":"POST","label":"Cherry Pick","title":"Cherry pick change to a different branch","enabled":true},"description":{"method":"PUT","label":"Edit Description","enabled":true},"rebase":{"method":"POST","label":"Rebase","title":"Rebase onto tip of branch or parent change.","enabled":true,"enabled_options":["rebase","rebase_on_behalf_of_uploader"]}}

Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.actions.ErrorAction$ErrorId: 49aaf903-ceee-4e7e-83d8-642316a37b95
groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is ')' with an int value of 41
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
)]}'
^
    at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeValueInternal(JsonParserCharArray.java:206)
    at groovy.json.internal.JsonParserCharArray.decodeValue(JsonParserCharArray.java:157)

my jenkinsfile is
    stages {
        stage('Read Json From Gerrit') {
            steps {
                script {
                        def response = sh(
                            script: "curl -u ${GERRIT_HTTP_USR}:${GERRIT_HTTP_PSW} -s '$GERRIT_API_URL_CHANGES/$GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER/revisions/$GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION/actions'",
                            returnStdout: true
                            ).trim()
                        echo "Raw Response: ${response}"
                        def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

All I want to do is just see if enabled is true? this one
"enabled":true


"and return is I believe json" - surprisingly, it's not. This question is similar to: How to filter out first few bad characters of Gerrit JSON api response. The code there is in Python but the root cause seems to be exactly the same because of the weird format of Gerrit API responses.


The error you're encountering is due to the extra characters at the beginning of the JSON response: )]}'. This is a common issue when dealing with JSONP responses or certain APIs that wrap their JSON responses.
To fix the issue, you need to remove the unwanted characters before parsing the JSON. Here’s how you can modify:
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

stages {
    stage('Read Json From Gerrit') {
        steps {
            script {
                def response = sh(
                    script: "curl -u ${GERRIT_HTTP_USR}:${GERRIT_HTTP_PSW} -s
                    '$GERRIT_API_URL_CHANGES/$GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER/revisions/$GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION/actions'",
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()

                echo "Raw Response: ${response}"

                // Remove the unwanted characters at the start
                def jsonResponse = response.replaceAll(/^\)\]}'.*/, '')

                // Parse the cleaned JSON response
                def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonResponse)

                // Check if 'enabled' is true
                def isEnabled = json.rebase?.enabled
                echo "Is Enabled: ${isEnabled}"
            }
        }
    }
}


Is Gerrit's prefix just the first line? In this case a regex would be overkill.

Just in case you are curious why the response looks the way it does, here is a link to the documentation:

To prevent against Cross Site Script Inclusion (XSSI) attacks, the JSON response body starts with a magic prefix line that must be stripped before feeding the rest of the response body to a JSON parser:

  )]}'
  [ ... valid JSON ... ]

